# Linux/KDE and "greedy" hotkeys

Tags: linux, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, kde

I've recently switched to Linux again, and this time I've decided to install KDE. I've set the layout cycling hotkey to <kbd>Ctrl+Shift</kbd>, but the problem is that it clashes with every other hotkey that begins with that combination. To be concrete, it clashes with Firefox' *restore last closed tab* combination of <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+T</kbd>. That worked flawlessly in Windows. It seems that KDE, or Linux in general, has "greedy" hotkeys by default. It doesn't wait to see if there's going to be a longer combination of the pressed keys.

Is there a remedy for this?